# Android: Efficiently ensuring that the pixels in a scaled bitmap have only two colors

Tags: android, image, scale

I have a bitmap whose pixels contain only two argb values: pure black and pure transparent. I then scale the bitmap up in Android, now the bitmap has many argb values: pure black and pure transparent and black with various levels of transparency (i.e half transparent black); this is due to the interpolation done automatically by android. I would like the bitmaps pixels to contain only the original two argb values.

Currently I accomplish this with the following process:

```
  my_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                            R.drawable.my_resource), 
                                  new_width, new height, false);

for (int i = 0; i < my_bitmap.getWidth(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < my_bitmap.getWidth(); j++) {
                    if (my_bitmap.getPixel(i, j) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        my_bitmap.setPixel(i, j, Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
        }
```

This is achingly slow on a cheaper phone for even a small bitmap, does anyone know how to either A) do this much faster or B) scale a bitmap up with no new argb values appearing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is an algorithmic one.

Bitmap operations are very expensive... perhaps you can cache the bitmap somewhere and only draw it when the interpolation is specifically requested?

My other idea would be to group some amount of pixels together and have a flag "hasChanged" or something like that, and set it to true when something is changed so the system knows it has to redraw that pixel group.  This way you don't redraw things more often than necessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, in a way you're right, but I still don't understand why this is so slow. Isn't a bitmap just a kind of multidimensional array that I could somehow iterate over without calling getPixel and setPixel? Maybe that would speed things up.

Comment: Yes, but it's very slow because the screen needs to redraw the bitmap every time the bitmap's hashCode changes.  The drawing is what's expensive, not the manipulation in memory.  That's why I suggested caching the bitmap so as to redraw it only once per operation.

Comment: I don't understand, this bitmap isn't on the screen when this operation takes place, and I thought that was enough. What additional steps do I have to take to cache it?

Answer (score 0):

Do the scale in code since the built-in algorithm isn't what you want. You'll avoid the interpolation that you don't want and you won't have to undo it. (Excuse any coding errors -- I wrote this without access to an IDE or compiler.)

```
my_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_resource);
int[] src = new int[my_bitmap.getWidth() * my_bitmap.getHeight()];
my_bitmap.getPixels(src, 0, my_bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, my_bitmap.getWidth(), my_bitmap.getHeight());
int[] dst = new int[new_width * new_height];
float scaleX = my_bitmap.getWidth() / new_width;
float scaleY = my_bitmap.getHeight() / new_height;
for (int y = 0; y < new_height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < new_width; x++) {
        int srcY = (int) (y * scaleY);
        int srcX = (int) (x * scaleX);
        dst[y*new_height + x] = src[srcY*my_bitmap.getHeight() + srcX];
    }
}
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dst, 0, new_width, new_width, new_height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```